# How can I update my NSTimer as I change the value of the time interval

Tags: ios, iphone, nstimer

I have an `NSTtimer` implemented and it's working fine. I also have the time interval argument connected to a `UISlider` for the `iPhone`. However when I change it's value the `NSTimer` is still running at the original time interval it does not get updated. How can I implement an `NSTimer` and have it change it's time interval as the value of my `UISlider` changes. Below is the line I am using for the `NSTimer`.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:mySlider.value 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(myMethod) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

I want it to constantly update it time interval with the value of the `UISlider`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't I'm afraid. Invalidate it with:

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

Then create a new one with the new time.  You may have to set it to nil first as well.

```
myTimer = nil;
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:mySlider.value 
                                           target:self 
                                         selector:@selector(myMethod) 
                                         userInfo:nil 
                                          repeats:YES];
```

Comment: do you think that this is the way to go if I want to implement a strobe light mode to to turn on and off the iPhone 4 LED

Comment: If you want a variable timer it is.  Think about the possibility of having two timers offset from each other as well, although that may not work for your application.

Comment: great well thanks for your help, i'll see if i can get it working.

Comment: dont forget to release (if necessary)

Comment: then it will crash as the above is autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using GCD

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval=1;
BOOL timerInvalidate=NO;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),
               ^{
                   while (!timerInvalidate){
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),
                    ^{
                    //your code;
                    });
                   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:timeInterval];
                   }

               });
```

And change the value of timeInterval from else where in the code.