# Change the time interval of a Timer

Tags: iphone, xcode, timer, nstimer, nstimeinterval

here is my question:
Is it possible to increase the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2` for example of "3" after 10 seconds in ViewDidLoad for example.
E.g., from this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(createNewImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

to this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(createNewImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

thank you
sorry for my english I french :/

Answer (score 1):

Reschedule the timer recursively like this:

```
float gap = 0.50;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) onTimer {
    gap = gap + .05;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

========

Or according to [How can I update my NSTimer as I change the value of the time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989179/how-can-i-update-my-nstimer-as-i-change-the-value-of-the-time-interval)

Invalidate it with:

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

Then create a new one with the new time. You may have to set it to nil first as well.

```
myTimer = nil;
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:mySlider.value 
                                           target:self 
                                         selector:@selector(myMethod) 
                                         userInfo:nil 
                                          repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setFireDate:` to reschedule the timer. You'll need to keep track of the timer in an ivar. For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSTimer *timer;

@synthesize timer=timer_;

- (void)setTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
  if (timer_ != aTimer) {
    [aTimer retain];
    [timer_ invalidate];
    [timer_ release];
    timer_ = aTimer;
  }

- (void)dealloc {
  [timer_ invalidate];
  [timer_ release];
}

...

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...];

...

self.timer.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3]; // reschedule for 3 seconds from now
```

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand hos to use setFireDate or how to keep track of timer in an ivar .can you explain more please ? :)